# Function in a function in a while loop can not update an outside class variable?

Tags: python, class

So this code runs correctly...

```
class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        for i in range(6):
            self.cards.append(i)

class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
    

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.player = Player()
        self.deck = Deck()
        
    def play_game(self):
        self.add_card()
        print(self.player.cards)
        
    def add_card(self):
        self.player.cards.append(self.deck.cards.pop())       
        
game = Game()
game.play_game()
```

But if I add `while True:` to the `play_game(self)` function like this...

```
   def play_game(self):
        while True: 
            self.add_card()
            print(self.player.cards)
```

It says it can not `pop()` from an empty list. So I assume the function within the while loop is not able to access the variable `self.player.cards`, within the same instance as the correctly stated code does. Am I right about that?

Basically I just want to understand why this doesn't work, and what is going on...?

I do apologize if my wording is not accurate, I am new to Python...

Thanks!

Comment: `list.pop` removes an item from the list. If you have that in an infinite loop, your list will eventually become empty from popping all of its items, and you will end up with what you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

seems to me that you have drawn all 6 cards from the deck and its `cards` list has gone empty